# Does $\arccos 2x-2\arccos \sqrt{1-x^2}=\pi$ have a solution in $[-0.5,0.5]?$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve $\arccos 2x-2\arccos \sqrt{1-x^2}=\pi$ for $x \in [-0.5,0.5].$

My attempt: If $\arccos: [-1,1]\rightarrow [0,\pi]$ then the above relation is not possible as $\arccos 2x = \pi, \arccos \sqrt{1-x^2}=0$ is not possible.

Now if $\cos: [-\pi,0]\rightarrow [-1,1],$ then for the above relation $-\pi \leq \arccos 2x \leq 0$ and $-\frac{\pi}{6}\leq \arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq 0.$ So, no $x$ is satisfying the relation.

Also if $\cos: [-2\pi,-\pi]\rightarrow [-1,1],$ then for the above relation $-2\pi \leq \arccos 2x \leq -\pi$ and $-2\pi\leq \arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq -2\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}.$ So, no $x$ is satisfying the relation.

Question: Is there any domain $D$ on which $\cos$ is bijective and some $x$ satisfies the above relation?

Answer (score 2):

If you require that the two $\arccos$ in your equation to be the same and be continuous,
then there is no solution, no matter which branch of $\arccos$ you choose to use.
$\newcommand{\ac}{\text{Arccos}}\newcommand{\integer}{\mathbb{Z}}$

Denote by $\ac$ the standard arccos function, namely $[-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$.
Note that the preimage of $1$ under $\cos$ is $2\pi\integer$,
and the preimage of $-1$ is $\pi+2\pi\integer$.
Thus, any branch of $\arccos$ must send $[-1,1]$ to either one of these:

1. $[2k\pi, (2k+1)\pi]$, where $\arccos$ is strictly decreasing
2. $[(2k-1)\pi, 2k\pi]$, where $\arccos$ is strictly increasing

for some $k\in\integer$.
In fact, we have an explicit description of any branch:
$$
\begin{align*}
\arccos(x) &= \ac (x) +2k\pi \\
\text{or } \arccos(x) &= -\ac (x) + 2k\pi
\end{align*}
$$
All these can be proved using the continuity assumption.
Now, we can convert all the $\arccos$ in the equation to $\ac$.
The problem becomes whether there exist $k\in\integer$ and $x\in[-0.5,0.5]$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
\ac(2x)-2\ac(\sqrt{1-x^2}) &= (2k+1)\pi.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that the expression on the left-hand side is independent of $k$,
so we simply compute the range of the expression on the left-hand side.
An easy calculation shows that there can be no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same conclusion of impossibility by a somewhat alternate route.

Let $\displaystyle ~\theta = \text{Arccos}(2x), ~\alpha = 2\text{Arccos} =\sqrt{1 - x^2} ~: ~-0.5 \leq x \leq 0.5.$

If you follow the standard convention that the range of the Arccos function requires that the angle must be in $~[0,\pi],~$ then $~\theta~$ must be $~\leq \pi,~$ and $~\alpha~$ must be $~\geq 0.$

Then, the only way that $~\theta - \alpha = \pi,~$ is if $~\theta = \pi, ~\alpha = 0.$  This is impossible because $~\alpha = 0 \implies x = 0 \implies \theta = \pi/2.$

---

However, suppose that the convention around the range of the ArcCos function is (very loosely) relaxed, so that the ArcCos function is (also) permitted to evaluate to an angle in $~[-\pi/2, 0].~$ Then, the following analysis shows that a solution is still not possible.

That is, suppose that you let

- $\sin(\alpha/2) = -x ~: ~0 \leq x \implies $ 
  $\sin(\alpha) = 2\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\alpha/2) = -2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \implies $ 
  $\sin^2(\alpha) = 4x^2(1 - x^2).$
- $\cos^2(\theta) = 4x^2 \implies \sin^2(\theta) = 1 - 4x^2.$

Then, since $~\theta - \alpha = \pi ~: ~\alpha < 0,~$ 
you have that $~\theta + |\alpha| = \pi.$

This implies that $~\sin^2(\theta) = \sin^2(\alpha).$

This implies that

$$1 - 4x^2 = 4x^2(1 - x^2) = 4x^2 - 4x^4.$$

Letting $~u = x^2,~$ this implies that

$$4u^2 - 8u + 1 = 0 \implies $$

$$u^2 = \frac{1}{8}
 ~\left[ ~8 \pm \sqrt{64 - 16} ~\right]
= \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}. \tag1 $$

So

$$u^2 = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2} \implies u = x^2 =  
~\left| ~\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2} ~\right|. \tag2 $$

However, since $~|x| \leq \dfrac{1}{2},~$ you have that
$~x^2~$ is required to be $~\leq \dfrac{1}{4}.$

Both $~\displaystyle ~\left| ~\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2} ~\right|~$ and
$~\displaystyle ~\left| ~\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2} ~\right|~$
violate that constraint.

Therefore, even if $~\dfrac{\alpha}{2}~$ is permitted to be in $~[-\pi/2, 0], ~$ no solution is possible.